# How far can a credit card balance go into the negative?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit, balance

Hypothetically, if kept overpaying a credit card such that the negative balance kept increasing to absurd amounts, what would happen?

For example, say I have a credit card with a line of $500.  When making a payment, I accidentally include an extra 0, and so, I end up with a negative balance of $10,000 (that is, I overpaid my credit card by $10,000).

Does that money sit forever as credit, or would the credit servicer eventually notify me and/or send me a check for the negative?

Is there an amount where the credit servicer gets a flag / notification, or I simply can't keep paying more to the card?

Comment: Related: [Can credit card be used as a debit card by making payments into credit card before even using it?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/33949/10997)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a negative balance on your credit card, you can call the issuer and have them send you a check for the amount. Some will do it automatically for large amounts or if it stays negative over some period of time.

Usually credit card issuers don't let paying more than the current balance, but it still can happen sometimes if you pay off your balance and then get a refund, for example.

Comment: Thank you.  So if a credit line is for $500, it can't go lower than -$500 usually?

Comment: That is interesting. I didn't know you could have a negative balance... Who the hell would pay more than their credit bill anyways? But I guess typos can occur.. I most definitely would not add an extra 0 it would probably be more likely that I am missing a digit.

Comment: @NuWin it happened to me several times with refunds after paying off. I got a check a couple of times, but most of the times it just stayed there for several days until some other purchase used it up

Comment: @littleadv well that type of negative balance makes sense. Overpaying into a negative balance doesn't. Upvote, I learned something today.

Comment: @user3898238 There is no limit set, i.e. $500 can go max -$500 ... it can go any amount. Generally overpaying by Large $$ cases are rare.

Comment: I've had -£12 on a card for well over a year [due to an error in overpayment], and the bank refuses to cough up. I've resolved not to use the card (it's costing them far more to post monthly statements than the interest they're getting on my money) and will let the card expire without renewal, when they will have to make a refund.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I had something like that with at&t... I had a negative balance of half a dollar left on my account when I closed my line, and they would keep sending me monthly statements for almost a year (a presorted stamp costs about 40 cents in the US), but they refused to refund me because it was "less than $1". At some point they stopped sending the statements, I'm guessing they just took the money.

Answer (score 2):

As with many questions here, while littleadv is correct, the real answer is "each bank may handle this differently." In my case, I was experimenting with my balance to see the impact of utilization, and I overpaid the current bill before the bill was issued.

[image]

The prior balance was paid, but then I sent a payment to bring my account to a credit balance.

Further down the statement appears the line -

> Your account has a credit balance. We can hold and apply this balance
>   against future purchases and cash advances, or refund it. If you would
>   like a check mailed to you in the amount of the credit balance, simply
>   call us and speak to a representative.

You can also see that the "revolving credit available" is above the line of credit, implying that someone with a $5000 credit line wanting to charge a $6000 engagement ring can send a higher payment to the account and then make that charge.

Comment: This matches my experience, described in [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/34052/10997).

Comment: Ha. I just +1 your answer which was voted down. Strange.